# How do I send the selected image's base64 to the freeimage.host api in my JS code?

Tags: javascript, post, typeerror, fetch-api

I am new to JS and am trying to make a web page which has a button which receives an image URL from my app and shows it. when the button is clicked, user gets to click the button and replace the image inside it by selecting one from their phone, which then should go to the freeimage.host API and in response i get the hosted URL which I send back to my app.

Here's the relevant js part of my code which is supposed to let the user replace the existing image in the button and when new image is selected, send the POST request to that API to upload -

```
document.getElementById("image-upload").addEventListener("change", function(event) {
  const file = event.target.files[0];
  const reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function(e) {
    const uploadedImage = document.createElement("div");
    uploadedImage.classList.add("uploaded-image");
    uploadedImage.style.backgroundImage = `url(${e.target.result})`;

    const existingImage = uploadButton.querySelector(".uploaded-image");
    if (existingImage) {
      uploadButton.removeChild(existingImage);
    }

    uploadButton.appendChild(uploadedImage);

    ThunkableWebviewerExtension.postMessage("Sending...");

    const data = {
      key: "<MY_API_KEY>",
      action: "upload",
      source: e.target.result,
      format: "json"
    };

    fetch("https://freeimage.host/api/1/upload/", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        const imageUrl = data.image.url;
        ThunkableWebviewerExtension.postMessage(imageUrl);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        ThunkableWebviewerExtension.postMessage("Error uploading image: " + error);
      });
  };

  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});
```

What's going wrong is I think I am failing to correctly integrate the API and am incorrectly sending the parameters requested, so I'm repeatedly getting:

> "Typeerror : failed to fetch".

What is it I am doing wrong here? I just want to send the selected image's base64 format to the API using a POST request. Also, I know the typeerror isn't related to CORS, as there's one more API I am using in this code which is also a POST request and it works fine (or that is not how it works?)...

Here's the api documentation link (https://freeimage.host/page/api), which says to add these parameters and send the post request -

[image]

Can someone advice on how should I implement this correctly?

---

Edit : I logged the data and here's what it said -

[image]

But when I send a POST request to another api, for eg. the [JSON Placeholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/guide/) api, it works perfectly fine and I get the data I sent back in the response. So why the CORS error on one api call and not on the other? In both I sent the `data` object. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the things you should try. 1. log the `data` you are sending in fetch request and make sure it is what you expect it to be. 2. Try moving key from data to url param, i.e, your url will now be `https://freeimage.host/api/1/upload/?key=12345.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, thanks for replying. So I added the key into the url and I logged the data and it said this - https://i.ibb.co/b1fNjkr/image.png (above is the `data` object, and then the error I am getting - looks like a CORS error).

But when I try sending a POST request to for eg. [JSON placeholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/guide/) api, it works perfectly fine? So why is the CORS error coming only in the freeimage.host api call and not when the other one is called? Kindly advice... Thanks!